# Spring Security filter is not getting called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have wrote custom filters in spring security, but the filter is not getting called. I have made sure this by adding log statements in filter class. Dont know where is missed or did it wrong. Find the code below:

**popUpClassFilter.java**

```
public class popUpClassFilter implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(popUpClass.class);

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //do some logic here if you want something to be done whenever
        //the user successfully logs in.
        log.debug("Entered into customfilter");

        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
        User user =  SecurityClass.getUserDetails();
        session.setAttribute("id", user.ID());
        session.setAttribute("state", user.State());

        //set our response to OK status
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        //since we have created our custom success handler, its up to us to where
        //we will redirect the user after successfully login
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("home");
    }
}
```

**Config.xml**

```
<bean id="popUpClass" class="myPackage.security.popUpClassFilter" />
    <security:http entry-point-ref="myAppAuthEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    .............
    <security:custom-filter after="LOGIN_FILTER" ref="popUpFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Adriaan hi. Sure from next time i will make an edit to the same post. I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="myPackage.security.popUpClassFilter" />
```

and add this

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login"  authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```